# How to Load a react components in an array and display them

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

So I have a list of components that I want to load and store in an array

e.g  `array = [<component1/>,<component2/>,<component3/>,]`

so this is my code and how I have structed everything to work

**Declarations:**

```
let components = []
```

**Loading components into array:**

```
useEffect(() => {
     for(let i=0;i<length;i++){
      components[i] = <RadioButtonRN
      data={roadsigns.signs_questions[i].answers}
      box={false}
      textColor={primary}
      initial={2}
      selectedBtn={(e) => selectedAnswer(e)}
      />
     }
     connsole.log(components)
   },[])
```

**Returning components for display:**

```
return (
    <div>
     {components}
   </div>
  );
};
```

Somehow this code does load the component into the array but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: `So I have a list of components that I want to load and store in an array` Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
import React  from "react";

function App() {
  const compArray = () => {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      arr.push(<Name />);
    }
    return arr;
  };


  return <>{compArray()}</>;
}

export default App;

function Name() {
  return <h1>Hello world </h1>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a `key` for each component. I'm fairly certain it should work once you do this (assuming the trailing `}` after your `return` is the end of the function.

For a simple `key` assignment:

```
components[i] = <RadioButtonRN
key={i}
data={roadsigns.signs_questions[i].answers}
...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want array of same components,

```
return < > {
    components.map((el, i) => < Yourcomponent key = {
        i
      }
      otherParams = {
        el
      }
      />)} <
      />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).